# IQKeyBoaredManager doesn't work properly in IOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, iqkeyboardmanager

I have the IQKeyboardManager version 5.0.6.  My view is like below.

[image: img_0526]

If I clicked on a textview for the firsttime, it works fine. See below image

[image: img_0527]

And then if I close the keyboard(by pressing done or return buttons) and click another textview, the textview isn't moving and the keyboarded covers the textview. see below image,

[image: img_0529]

After that if I close the keyboard, my view is look like the below image,

[image: img_0530]

This happens in my all the other similar views as well. But this happens only in IOS 11. I have tested this in a IOS 10 device and IQKeyboardManager worked perfectly.

I have asked about this issue in the IQKeyboardManager GitHub page also. 
[Here](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/issues/1144) is the link for the issue. But I didn't got any answers.

If anyone knows any solution for this please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue occurred to me.
I updated the pod and it worked fine.

Use pod update IQKeyboardManager or if using swift remove IQKeyboardManager and instead try using IQKeyboardManagerSwift.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I tried your solution. But it didn't work.